# C++ WinSock2: WSA_INVALID_HANDLE on connect() call

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock, winsock2

Good day!

I'm a somewhat experienced programmer in higher level languages, but this is my first time diving into socket code on lower level languages, so please bear with me.

I seem to be getting an error upon the `connect()` call.  In my main function, `WSAGetLastError()` prints that this is error number 6 which according to MSDN is `WSA_INVALID_HANDLE`.  This seems strange as there is no detailing of that particular error code on the [MSDN page for the `connect()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (unless I'm going blind), and my google searches are all inconclusive

I'm using a custom socket_t structure as my code is designed to (eventually) be cross platform.  The `socket_connect()` function is called from the main code page.

`socket_t` definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    //windows-specific
    SOCKADDR_IN *addr_in;
    u_long mode;
    SOCKET socket;//acutal SOCKET structure

    // General
    bool listening;//set to true if actively listening
    bool thread_terminate;//when boolean is set to true, listening thread terminates
    void (*error_callback) (int);
    http_response_t * response;
} socket_t;
```

`socket_connect()` function:

```
//see socket_t definition in socket.h
//returns 0 on success, SOCKET_ERROR on WinSock failure, positive error code on ANSI DNS failure
int socket_connect(socket_t * sock, char * addr, int port)
{
    //bear in mind sock is the custom socket_t structure.  sock->socket is the actual SOCKET structure.
    //pardon the nomenclature.  rookie code.

    //DNS lookup structures
    struct addrinfo     * res           = NULL;// Result of the getaddrinfo() call
    struct sockaddr_in  * sockaddr_v4   = NULL;// IPv4 sockaddr structure

    // So-called "hints" structure detailed in the getaddrinfo() MSDN page.
    // I guess it contains information for the DNS lookup.
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family     = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol   = IPPROTO_TCP;

    //Perform DNS lookup
    DWORD getaddrinfo_res = getaddrinfo(addr, "80\0", &hints, &res);//hard-code Port number for now...
    if(getaddrinfo_res != 0) return getaddrinfo_res;//positive DNS error code

            //debug information
    std::cout << "DNS lookup responses:" << std::endl;
    //for each
    int i = 0;//counter
    for(struct addrinfo * ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        std::cout << "Response number " << i + 1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Flags: " << ptr->ai_flags << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Family: ";
        switch(ptr->ai_family)
        {
        case AF_INET:
            sockaddr_v4 = (struct sockaddr_in *) ptr->ai_addr;//set current address
            sock->addr_in = sockaddr_v4;//set socket address

            std::cout << "AF_INET (IPv4)" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Addr: " << inet_ntoa(sockaddr_v4->sin_addr) << std::endl;
            break;
        case AF_UNSPEC:
            std::cout << "UNSPECIFIED" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "UNKNOWN\t(" << ptr->ai_family << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    //initialize actual SOCKET
    sock->socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);// TCP/IP, stream-oriented, and TCP rather than UDP; respectively
    if(sock->socket == INVALID_SOCKET) return SOCKET_ERROR;

    //actual connection
    std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    int connect_res = connect(sock->socket, (SOCKADDR *) sockaddr_v4, sizeof(sockaddr_v4));///have to convert SOCKADDR_IN to a SOCKADDR pointer here.  Not sure why.
    if(connect_res == SOCKET_ERROR) return SOCKET_ERROR;

    //make nonblocking
    /*
    sock->mode = 1;
    int ioctl = ioctlsocket(sock->socket, FIONBIO, &(sock->mode));//I/O Control Socket.  Not sure what FIONBIO means.  pointer to sock->mode = 1 ensures nonblockingness.
    if(ioctl == SOCKET_ERROR) return SOCKET_ERROR;
    */// (include this?)

    return 0;
}
```

`socket_connect()` function call:

```
int connect_res = conley::socket_connect(sock, "www.google.com", 80);
if(connect_res > 0) std::cout << "DNS ERR " << connect_res << std::endl << std::endl;
if(connect_res < 0) std::cout << "CONNECT ERR " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl << std::endl;
if(connect_res == 0) std::cout << "Connected" << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Thank you for your time!
- Jake

Comment: Trivial questions first. Did you properly initialize WinSock using [`WSAStartup()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I do believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong size for you `sockaddr_in` when you're calling connect.

Change this:

```
int connect_res = connect(sock->socket, (SOCKADDR *) sockaddr_v4, sizeof(sockaddr_v4));
//                                                            wrong size ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To this:

```
int connect_res = connect(sock->socket, (SOCKADDR *) sockaddr_v4, sizeof(*sockaddr_v4));
//                                                            right size  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Beyond that, your program has a different bug, namely the persistance of the `getaddrinfo()` - returned pointer in your `sock` structure. That should be copied out by value into memory owned by `sock`. It will work with this sample because it is so isolated, but it should be changed.

Comment: Ah, makes total sense now.  Thank you!